# python3 запись в файл xlsx библиотека openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, excel, запись, openpyxl

не могу догадаться как в моём случае произвести запись в каждую нужную ячейку

```
import os 
import openpyxl
cwd = os.getcwd()
cwd
os.chdir("/path/to/file")
os.listdir('.')
fullsheet = openpyxl.load_workbook('./base.xlsx')
completesheet = openpyxl.load_workbook('./completed_base.xlsx')
sheet = fullsheet['Sheet1']
sheet2 = completesheet['Лист1']
for i in range (1, sheet.max_row):  
    defnum = str(sheet.cell(row=i, column=sheet.max_column).value)
    digits = []
    for sym in defnum:
        if '1234567890'.find(sym) != -1:
            digits.append(str(sym))
    defnumeditstr = ''.join(digits)
    for j in range (1, sheet2.max_row):
        delnum = str(sheet2.cell(row=j , column=1).value)
        b = defnumeditstr.find(delnum)
        if b == 0 or b == 11:
#           sheet.cell(row=i , column = sheet.max_column) = '+' вот здесь должна быть запись нового значения в ячейку
fullsheet.save(filename='rafa.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sheet.cell(row=i , column = sheet.max_column , value = '+')
```